# want to display the parent and child value?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

i need to display the parent and child value. but here i have got the value only one side. but i need both sides.

for example:

i have list like below:

```
title1
  yellow
  pink

title2
  green
  rose
```

if i drag the yellow and place it into title2. then i have to display the value of parent and child like this

```
title1_pink(yellow drag and placed it into title2)
title2_green
title2_yellow
title3_rose
```

here fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/mwypv/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
var origTitle;
var origColor;
$(".droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.mt",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        origColor = ui.item.text();
        origTitle = ui.item.parent().siblings('.Tbltitle').text();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var order = [];

        ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
            order.push($(this).data('position'));
            var c = $(this).text();
            if (c === origColor) {
                var z = origTitle;
            } else {
                var z = $(this).parent().siblings('.Tbltitle').text();
            }
            $("#cl").append(z + "_" + c + "<br />");
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/mwypv/17/